# Massive data combobox with Kendo UI virtualization not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm trying to create a combobox with pagination (virtualization) using Kendo UI and Angular JS:

The idea is to bring 10000 items in pages of 10. Using [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/virtualization) and [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering) Kendo Demos I get this far:

**HTML:**

```
<select kendo-combo-box k-options="config"></select>
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
$scope.config = {
    template: "<span>#= key # - #= value #</span>",
    dataTextField: "key",
    dataValueField: "value",
    virtual: {
        itemHeight: 26,
        valueMapper: function (options) {
            console.log("valueMapper was executed.");
        },
    },
    height: 156,
    dataSource: {
        //type: "odata", // comment explained below
        pageSize: 24,
        serverPaging: true,
        //serverFiltering: true,
        schema: {
            total: "total",
            data: "data"
        },
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                console.log("dataSource transport read was called.");
                // ajax call with result object => response.
                options.success(response);
            }
        },
    }
};
```

**JSON response object** (in `transport read` function):

```
{
    "total": "10000",
    "data": [
        { "key": "1", "value": "a" },
        { "key": "2", "value": "b" },
        ...
        { "key": "9", "value": "j" }
    ]
}
```

PS: `"data"` has 10 elements.

This is not working. The combo is created with 10 items and nothing more.

If I uncomment the lines:

```
type: "odata",
serverFiltering: true,
```

The combobox is build with 10000 items with `"loading..."` as description. But no matter how much time I wait, this "loading..." texts are never updated to my information, and more, the line:

```
console.log("dataSource transport read was called.");
```

keep getting hit in infinity loop.

Before finishes I notice other strange behavior. The function in `valueMapper` is never executed (the message `"valueMapper was executed." is never printed.`).

And if I set `virtual: false` no pagination is used.

How can I make this work?

Comment: What happens if you define your read as just "function (options) { ... }" instead of "function (options): void { ... }" ?  I don't think that is valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that, I copied from a TypeScript file, but miss this adaptation. The question was updated.